# Select all columns from database same as present time using C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I have written a query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE CAST(DateField as Date) = CAST(GetDate() as Date)
```

Now I also want to add time which same as present time from the database.

Simply how could I get records from database whose date and time match presents date and time.

Comment: Present time? Up to a second? Millisecond?

Comment: Present date and time it is moment!

Comment: Your query is correct. What is your question?

Comment: You're querying to a millisecond's precision, so you're not likely to get many records coming back in your query...

Comment: @martin_costello `CAST(GetDate() as Date)` will get the date part only, so there is no millisecond comparison.

Comment: It will never return anything if you go for the precision of the millisecond. **Time has this strange tendency of not sitting still.**

Comment: Can you provide example of the data that is in your **DateField**. For example is it down to the milliseconds: _2014-04-22 11:18:17.177_ or just to the minute: _2014-04-22 11:18_.

Comment: believe me you'll never get record with millisecond time comparison, atleast you have to cast datetime upto second part, plz mention precise requirement of query.

Comment: Can anyone say me which is right?                                                          SELECT * FROM Table1 
   WHERE (CAST(date AS Date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)) AND 
         (CAST(time AS time(7)) = CAST(GETDATE() AS time(7)))


    SELECT * FROM Table1 
    WHERE CAST(date AS Date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date) AND 
     (time = { fn CURTIME() })";

Answer (score 1):

There are so many functions for datetime. Please check the following link.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp

You can use DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type) or DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr type) functions to add or substract time to any date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DATEPART() to return a certain part of the date or time and then choose which parts you want to compare, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE CAST(DateField as Date) = CAST(GetDate() as Date) AND DATEPART(hour,GetDate()) = DATEPART(hour,DateField)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE CAST(DateField as Datetime) = CAST(GetDate() as DateDatetime)
```

Comment: 1) What is a `DateDatetime`? 2) A little explanation can go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

I have written query as below. Is that right?

my time is in time(7) format and date is in date format.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CAST(date AS Date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS Date)) AND (time = { CURTIME() })
```

I am using Sqlserver and c#.